# How to find existing and add an attribute to image tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have below  tag in HTML, which is not having class or parent div to identify since its dynamic content will load anywhere inside to body.
**My expectation is how to find this img tag and how to inject "alt tag" to this image alone!? Please help me in javascript. Thanks in advance**
*Note: I have more static images in a page which I can add alt tags*

```html
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/12/e2/6d/12e26d72c68442640b27583cff8d50e7.png" width="100" height="100" style="display: block">
```

Comment: share your html with example.

Answer (score 3):

You can select the image tag by its `src` attribute:

```js
const image = document.querySelector('img[src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/12/e2/6d/12e26d72c68442640b27583cff8d50e7.png"]');
image.alt = 'alt tag';
console.log(image);
```

```html
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/12/e2/6d/12e26d72c68442640b27583cff8d50e7.png" width="100" height="100" style="display: block">
```

Comment: If the image is dynamically loaded, then might it not be present at the time of script execution?

Comment: @Frish I'm assuming OP is simply trying to figure out how to select the images.

Comment: Thank you. This code is working. Is there any other way to find the tag except the file name?. If yes then it will be more efficient solution for me!.

Comment: @johny If there are no classes and ids, selecting by the `src` attribute is the only way to go.

Comment: @Spectric Thanks. in this img tag we have inline (style="display: block"). Will this help us to identify something? since this inline style never changed it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable to the image and do whatever you want with it.

```js
function createIMG(alt){
const flowerIMG = document.createElement("img")
flowerIMG.src = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/12/e2/6d/12e26d72c68442640b27583cff8d50e7.png"
flowerIMG.width="100"
flowerIMG.height="100"
flowerIMG.display="block"
flowerIMG.alt = alt
document.body.appendChild(flowerIMG)
}

createIMG("FLOWERS")
```

This way you can create the image in a function and the alt can change. You can also set the other attributes to arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your code. But this <img> will render dynamic only so, cant to do anything with in this tag..

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic. Like when you press a button the image would load?

Comment: Dynamic sense the <img> tag will generate automatically and load in page without triggering of any events ( onclick or onchange). My scenario is even i don't know where the code is written !!.

Comment: I edited it so you can call it in functions

Comment: Thanks. This code will support for static <img> code.